# How to turn a permutations function into a lazy generator?

Tags: javascript, generator, permutation

I am trying to get all of the permutations of an array, one permutation at time, using a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

This is the original code (which works as intended and returns an array of permutations), and below is my attempt to change it:

```
function permutations(iList, maxLength) {
        const cur = Array(maxLength)
        const results = []

        function rec(list, depth = 0) {
            if (depth === maxLength) {
                return results.push(cur.slice(0))
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                cur[depth] = list.splice(i, 1)[0]
                rec(list, depth + 1)
                list.splice(i, 0, cur[depth])
            }
        }
        rec(iList)
        return results
    }
```

My code, which returns nothing:

```
function* permutations2(iList, maxLength) {
    const cur = Array(maxLength)

    function* rec(list, depth = 0) {
        if (depth === maxLength) {
            yield cur.slice(0)
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            cur[depth] = list.splice(i, 1)[0]
            rec(list, depth + 1)
            list.splice(i, 0, cur[depth])
        }
    }
    yield rec(iList)
 }
```

For example, for `print(permutations2([1, 2, 3], 2))`
I want to get

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
```

However with the original code I am getting an array of the permutations:

```
[[1, 2],
[1, 3],
[2, 1],
[2, 3],
[3, 1],
[3, 2]]
```

I would be grateful to understand why my code is not working, and how to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to make a **lazy** generator that only computes values as they are being needed?

Comment: @kelly Yes - I do not need all of the permutation at once - only a single one every time. After I used it I no longer need it, and I can move on to the next permutation.

Comment: An sample input array with expected output should be included in the details of this question.

Comment: @jsejcksn You are totally right - I added an example

Answer (score 1):

A lazy generator will take some more work.

Instead of returning your results now, you use `yield*` to yield all the results that will come forth from `rec`.

Now `rec` is also a generator function.

And in a similar manner, instead of `return` and adding onto our results array, we `yield` the result.

Something you need to change here is adding the `else`, because `yield` does not stop the rest of the function from executing. It's only a pause. That's why we need `else` to make sure that this code does not execute after we yield.

Inside the `else`, like above, whenever we call `rec`, we need to yield the results of `rec` as well.

```js
function* permutations(iList, maxLength) {
    const cur = Array(maxLength)

    function* rec(list, depth = 0) {
        if (depth === maxLength) {
            yield cur.slice(0);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                cur[depth] = list.splice(i, 1)[0];

                yield* rec(list, depth + 1);

                list.splice(i, 0, cur[depth])
            }
        }
    }

    yield* rec(iList);
}

console.log([...permutations([1, 2, 3], 2)]);
```

This seems to produce the same results but it is lazy now.

Comment: Thanks - this is seems to be working.
I modified my code like this:
Instead of `for (const perm of permutations([1, 2, 3], 2))` to 
`const generator = permutations([1, 2, 3], 2)`
`let perm = generator.next()`
`while (perm.done === false){ .... ; perm = generator.next(); `

Answer (score -1):

This is actually all the change you need, generator function, then `yield*` instead of `return`.

```js
function* permutations(iList, maxLength) {
    const cur = Array(maxLength)
    const results = []

    function rec(list, depth = 0) {
        if (depth === maxLength) {
            return results.push(cur.slice(0))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            cur[depth] = list.splice(i, 1)[0]
            rec(list, depth + 1)
            list.splice(i, 0, cur[depth])
        }
    }
    rec(iList);
    yield* results;
}

console.log([...permutations([1, 2, 3], 2)]);
```

Note that this creates a generator that is not lazy. It computes all of the values beforehand and then yields them all.

[`yield*` is a short way to yield all elements of an iterable or another generator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*)

Comment: How can I modify this into a lazy generator?

Comment: This generates every permutation in advance, then only yields them one at a time. My interpretation of the OP's question (and one of the advantages of the concept of iteration) is that they want to delay the work to only be done during each iteration cycle.

Comment: @jsejcksn yes - exactly as you said. How can I achieve that?